# How to make Internet browser?

Tags: android, browser

I made a simple browser app using Webview, 
but Existing  android Browser apps like Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Firefox.

How are these apps made?
Simply same using Webview??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read what is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes basically they are WebViews. And web engine it self for webView is used default one installed on device, it also can be changed in phone settings.